# How to remove duplicate files based on substring in file name from unix directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix

There are files in UNIX directory like :

```
5134909_GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.DAT
5132888_GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.DAT
5134909_GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.CTL
5132807_GRUP88_SRE323_20210930.DAT
5132925_GRUP88_SRE323_20210930.DAT
```

from these files I want to find and remove files with matching string (**GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.DAT** and **GRUP88_SRE323_20210930.DAT**) keeping only one copy.

I found below code to find duplicate but it finds based on md5sum which is giving incorrect result for me:

`find . ! -empty -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort | uniq -w32 -dD`

Could you please help in this. Let me know if more information required.

Comment: Why are the strings matching? What is the expected output?

Comment: The reason that code is doing an MD5 check is because it is checking the files to see if the *contents* are duplicated, not the *name*. You tagged the question [Python]. If you want to do this job in Python show us what you tried and explain why it doesn't work. You also need to explain why  you consider `GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.DAT` to match `GRUP88_SRE323_20210930.DAT`.

Comment: Do we use for uniqueness GRUP88 or 20210930 or both?

Comment: Problem is , few files generated twice so I want to remove those files from directory.  From this file name "5134909_GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.DAT" - '5134909' is dynamic and rest string is same. So wanted to delete duplicate file based on substring "GRUP88_SRE355_20210930.DAT".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate lines based on partial text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304300/remove-duplicate-lines-based-on-partial-text) I know it is with `awk` but can give you the idea about the logic

Comment: Here I want to delete files.